# Shopify not redirecting to external links

Tags: shopify

So, I added a whatsapp bubble to my website using the code below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href=“https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5571999002047&text=Oi,%20estou%20no%20site%20da%20Teare%20e%20gostaria%20de%20tirar%20uma%20dúvida...” style="position:fixed;width:60px;height:60px;bottom:40px;right:40px;background-color:#25d366;color:#FFF;border-radius:50px;text-align:center;font-size:30px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  z-index:1000;" target="_blank">
<i style="margin-top:16px" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```

This added the bubble alright. But when I click it, its not redirecting to the link in the code. Instead, Shopify is adding its own url before the url I added. Like this:

```
https://tearetapetes.com.br/“https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5571999002047&text=Oi,%20estou%20no%20site%20da%20Teare%20e%20gostaria%20de%20tirar%20uma%20dúvida...”
```

How can I fix that? You can test it. Thanks.

Bubble (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqN6N.jpg)
Wrong url (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8nGJ.png)

Didn't try anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the URL is not correct which you added to the website.

This type of comma a not correct.

`“https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5571999002047&text=Oi,%20estou%20no%20site%20da%20Teare%20e%20gostaria%20de%20tirar%20uma%20dúvida...”`

use this format

`"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5571999002047&text=Oi,%20estou%20no%20site%20da%20Teare%20e%20gostaria%20de%20tirar%20uma%20dúvida..."`

Use like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5571999002047&text=Oi,%20estou%20no%20site%20da%20Teare%20e%20gostaria%20de%20tirar%20uma%20dúvida..." style="position:fixed;width:60px;height:60px;bottom:40px;right:40px;background-color:#25d366;color:#FFF;border-radius:50px;text-align:center;font-size:30px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  z-index:1000;" target="_blank">
<i style="margin-top:16px" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: "This type of comma a not correct" ??  you do mean the [Quotation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)

Comment: `“”` is not the correct format, did you check the href of pasted into question?